# Laravel connection to sqlserv

Tags: sql-server, laravel, connection

I'm getting error: 
"**SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (severity 9)**"
when I try to get answer from server by

```
$users = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select('Select quotation_username from users');
```

and yes - I have set:

```
 'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST2', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT2', '1433'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE2', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME2', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD2', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```

Any feedback would be appreciated :)

EDIT:

I tried "php arsian serve" as suggested and got an error message:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/sqlsrv' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/sqlsrv: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

.env content:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=inventoryapp
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=****

DB_CONNECTION2=sqlsrv
DB_HOST2=****
DB_PORT2=1433
DB_DATABASE2=i4
DB_USERNAME2=****
DB_PASSWORD2=****
```

Answer (score 1):

There is file called .env in the root folder, set the **DB_HOST2** and **DB_PORT2** value there.

after that re-run the **php artisan serve**

Comment: I'v set values. But php artisan serve gave me an error that I'll add to question

Comment: check the value and be sure you put it the right value

Comment: also, paste the .env content